# Wordpress uploads error - is not writing to database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, upload

I've recently moved my WordPress blog from one server to another, changing the URL paths. I decided to use a subdomain for images and uploads.

After I upload an image I get this error:

> "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

I changed URL paths in the database so all the existing uploads are showing as expected. The new uploads will be uploaded in /static/uploads separated by year and month.

**The image is not added to the database**. After several attempts to upload I went to the uploads directory via FTP and confirmed the uploads were present, but for some reason they were not written to the database.

I would like to correct this so the uploads are both written to the server and the database.

I don't have example code or otherwise and didn't get a chance to review error logs.

Any fix or help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: without source code, it's anybody's guess.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to give source code. It's Wordpress just with upload paths changed.

Comment: @EduardoPérez you did something wrong with changing the wp settings and this is the cause of your problems. You did it by code and we cannot know what you did and what went wrong without looking at that code

Comment: @LelioFaieta No, i didn't change the paths via wp-settings.php as this is deprecated. Instead I went to wp-admin/options.php and modified both paths there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have a copy of the old database, try replacing the old domain or URL with a new one by fixing the serialized data as well as the paths.

> A serialized string not only stores the value of a object but also its size (number of characters) therefore if the old and the new domains or URLs have different character counts, PHP will not be able to recreate the original object anymore.

[WordPress Serialized PHP Search and Replace](http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/)

Comment: It was a serialization problem. thanks!

Comment: No problem - I had similar issues awhile back and it took forever to narrow down the culprit. Specifically, I experienced this kind of problem switching themes and loosing all of my widgets. Serialized data - smh :)

Comment: Ooooooooh! That's why I also lost all my widget configuration hahahaha! Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem. I'm sure you'll get it all worked out. Cheers!